# How to merge a row with a matrix, and output a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

Being a beginner, I have a very basic question. When a I merge a vector with a matrix using data.frame function, the vector always merges as a column. In this way, data.frame works as the cbind function, however, the integrity of the data, i.e. class does not loose. I want to know how can I merge a row in a matrix while using data frame function? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we need to append a 'vector' as row to an existing 'matrix' and output as 'data.frame', we can use `rbind`

```
res <- rbind.data.frame(m1, v2)
res
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  1  3  5  7
#2  2  4  6  8
#3  1  2  3  4

str(res)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ V1: int  1 2 1
# $ V2: int  3 4 2
#$ V3: int  5 6 3
# $ V4: int  7 8 4
```

For `cbind`, I guess you mentioned this:

```
data.frame(m1, v1)
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 v1
#1  1  3  5  7  1
#2  2  4  6  8  2
```

Suppose, we have a 'character' vector ('v3') and a numeric matrix ('m1'), the `data.frame(m1, v3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` will preserve the class of the 'v3' as 'character'.  But, if we are doing `rbind.data.frame` on a similar vector ('v4'), this will convert all the columns to 'character'.

#### data

```
 m1 <- matrix(1:8, ncol=4)
 v1 <- 1:2
 v2 <- 1:4
 v3 <- as.character(v1)
 v4 <- as.character(v2)
```